# fast parsing links out of a page in python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to parse a large number of pages (say 1000) and replace the links with tinyurl links.

right now i am doing this using a regex

```
href_link_re = re.compile(r"<a[^>]+?href\s*=\s*(\"|')(.*?)\1[^>]*>", re.S)
```

but its not fast enough.

i am thinking so far

1. state machine (the success of this will depend on my ability to write clever code)
2. using an html parser

Can you suggest **faster** ways?

**EDIT:**
You would think that an html parser would be faster than regex, but in my tests it is not:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

import re
import time

__author__ = 'misha'

regex = re.compile(r"<a[^>]+?href\s*=\s*(\"|')(.*?)\1[^>]*>", re.S)

def test(text, fn, desc):

    start = time.time()
    total  = 0
    links = [];
    for i in range(0, 10):
        links = fn(text)
        total += len(links)
    end = time.time()
    print(desc % (end-start, total))
   # print(links)

def parseRegex(text):
    links  = set([])
    for link in regex.findall(text):
        links.add(link[1])
    return links

def parseSoup(text):
    links = set([])
    for link in BeautifulSoup(text, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_key('href'):
            links.add(link['href'])

    return links



if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open('/Users/misha/test')
    text = ''.join(f.readlines())
    f.close()

    test(text, parseRegex, "regex time taken: %s found links: %s" )
    test(text, parseSoup, "soup time taken: %s found links: %s" )
```

output:

```
regex time taken: 0.00451803207397 found links: 2450
soup time taken: 0.791836977005 found links: 2450
```

(test is a dump of the wikipedia front page)

i must be using soup badly. **what am i doing wrong?**

Comment: Couldn't you simplify your code by first looking for `<a` and then inspecting the matches further afterwards.

Comment: yes, and that would be the state machine route

Comment: Why would an HTML parser be faster than regex? Besides, BeautifulSoup is largely Python code, whereas the re module is C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LXML is probably your best bet for this task. See [Beautiful Soup vs LXML Performance](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2010/08/16/beautifulsoup-vs-lxml-performance/). Parsing links is easy in LXML and it's fast.

```
root = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
anchors = root.cssselect("a")
links = [a.get("href") for a in anchors]
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing using regexp's very bad idea, because of speed and regexp exponential time problem.
Instead you can use parsers for xhtml. The best is [LXML](http://lxml.de/).
Or you can write parser specially for this purpose with LL,LR parsers. For example: [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/),[YAPPS](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/yapps/),[YACC](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/),[PYBISON](http://www.freenet.org.nz/python/pybison/), etc

Comment: I remember this legendary SO post every time a question is posted involving using regexes to parse html. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Which is faster: LXML or Beautiful Soup? I've been using the latter, but it seems like I see the former being recommended more often these days

Comment: LXML is native parser, while Beautiful Soup use reg exps for parsing. So LXML is better.